# onRestart() and onRefresh() Act Different with Same Code

Tags: android, location, oncreate

I have the exact same methods and calls in onRefresh() and onRestart(), but for some reason onRestart() does what I want exactly, yet onRefresh() acts differently. What I want to happen is for app to understand when the location is disabled while running.

onRestart() does this: I start the app, get the Forecast data, disable location from status bar, press the home button and open the app again. As expected, onRestart() tries to check for GPS status(with gpsTracker.getIsGPSEnabled()), sees that location is disabled, and sends the according Toast message.

onRefresh() does this: I start the app, get the Forecast data, disable location from status bar, even wait few seconds and then refresh the app. Unexpectedly, onRefresh() gives sends the "Data Refreshed" toast, even though it gets "null, null" as location latitude and longitude.

I could provide other codes as well, but if there was a problem with the rest of the code, why would onRestart() act the way I want? I'm not getting any errors. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    final GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);


    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    if (gpsTracker.getIsGPSTrackingEnabled()) {
                        gpsTracker.getLocation();
                        getForecast(gpsTracker);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    final GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
    new Handler().postDelayed (new Runnable ()
       @Override public void run() {
            gpsTracker.getLocation();
            if (gpsTracker.getIsGPSTrackingEnabled()) {
                getForecast(gpsTracker);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
}, 3000);
}
```

Comment: do you have the permission for the app to access the location ? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: @ImDeveloping yes, I don't have any issues with getting the forecast for current location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
            final GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                if (gpsTracker.getIsGPSTrackingEnabled()) {
                    gpsTracker.getLocation();
                    getForecast(gpsTracker);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: That solved it. I totally missed that :( Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

onRestart you create a new instance of GPSTracker. try updating your GPSTracker handler in onRefresh.
give it a try

Comment: That solved it. I totally missed that :( Thanks a lot.